# Rainloop on IIS 8.5 with PHP 7

Tags: php, iis

I try to install Rainloop on IIS 8.5 with PHP 7.

I get a first error:

```
[202] Data folder permissions error [is_writable]
```

I've tried to edit folder rights and added this to web.config :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <add segment="data"/>
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permissions to both users:

1) IIS AppPool\AppPoolName (replace "AppPoolName" with the name of your website's application pool).

2) IUSR